# How can I set a cookie to remember the last login users Name and Email

Tags: php, cookies, sessionid

How can i set a cookie to remember certain user details from previous session. What i want the browser to remember is the users Name and Email address and auto fill the users details except their password so that the login is convenient i want this to be remembered by a cookie.

**I have already tried the following...**

```
<?php 
    $username = '$flname';
    $useremail = '$email';
    setcookie('csm_remember_pre-session', $username, $useremail, time()+7200); //Remember Previous User for two hours only
    $_COOKIE['csm_remember_pre-session'];
?>
```

Comment: With [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie). Please be a bit more specific with what you tried, or what actual coding or design issue you face.

Comment: If you're working with a database and would like to build queries with these cookies, you should use $_SESSION instead as cookies are user editable

Comment: @mario i am trying to set a cookie to remember the users name an email to display when user tries to login again just enter password please see what [Google does](https://accounts.google.com)

Comment: is my question back on topic

Comment: You still haven't articulated a problem you need help with, so no.

Comment: @coreyward can you lift my ask question ban

Comment: @coreyward can you lift my ask question ban, i have fixed my problem and it now remembers the user when he/she checks the remember me input.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$value = 'ben';

// Adding
setcookie('username', $value, time()+3600); // Expire in 1 hour

// Getting
$_COOKIE['username']; // ben
```

Comment: What other script details would you like ?

Comment: what details would you like, i already set a remember me function